# How to use clustering in h2o driverless AI GUI

Tags: h2o

I am new to H2O, I installed H2O Driverless AI in evaluation license. I can successfully perform visualisation and classification model prediction. But I'm wondering how to start with clustering. Because I don't find any option for unsupervised learning or clustering technique? where should i perform clustering operation in driverless AI? Is Clustering operation available in Driverless AI or not?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, as of version 1.2.0, unsupervised clustering is not supported in DAI; DAI is designed to solve supervised learning problems.

Here are the current supported problem types (**please review the documentation** to see changes of future releases at http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/latest-stable/docs/userguide/release_notes.html):

**Problem types supported**:

- Regression (continuous target variable, for age, income, house price,
  loss prediction, time-series forecasting)
- Binary classification (0/1
  or “N”/”Y”, for fraud prediction, churn prediction, failure
  prediction, etc.)
- Multinomial classification (0/1/2/3 or
  “A”/”B”/”C”/”D” for categorical target variables, for prediction of
  membership type, next-action, product recommendation, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the both answers.